# How to control Playstation 3 without a controller and with a pc

Tags: ps3

How can we do it? I tried all the apps on it but could not find any that worked.

My controllers are not working and I have special information and data in it.

Comment: Is there anything to make you think you **can** do this?

Comment: Don't downvote people for not knowing stuff. That's explictly against the rules of the site.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put.  This isn't possible.

But there are programs that allow you to  remove data from the internal hard drive after removing the hard drive and plugging the hard drive into a PC motherboard.

Or you could just buy new controllers.